# Why is ssh looking for identity files?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have a problem with turning off key authentication in `ssh`. I want to connect to remote server with password, but `ssh` is always looking for these identity files:

```
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
```

I configured `~/.ssh/config` file to use only password authentication like this:

```
Host *
    RSAAuthentication no
    PreferredAuthentications password
    PubkeyAuthentication no
```

I also added this to general `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file, but when trying to access SVN server via ssh it's still looking for these files. I am clueless on how to further configure `ssh`.

Comment: You would need to use the IdentityFile definition in the config file and I'm pretty sure that there needs to be an entry so I'm not sure you can disable it.

Comment: Yes when I define identity file in config file then it starts looking for that IF, but there is no way to disable it?

Comment: I'm afraid that it's also possible to require the authentication type on the server side in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: I turned off key authentification in /etc/ssh/sshd_config as well.

Comment: Is your concern that these `debug1` statements appear in verbose connection output, or that there is [some sort of connection problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you are assuming that it is related to these `debug1` statements?  If you cannot connect to a remote server, it could be helpful if you paste the full verbose output (sanitized of any identifying information), rather than just these three lines.

Comment: @user4556274 My concern is that connection is closed after these lines appear.

Comment: debug1: Connecting to ... port 443.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: loaded 3 keys
    ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    ... Network connection closed unexpectedly

Comment: sorry I don't know how to format code here :/

Comment: The connection closes after `ssh_exchange_identification` because there is no remote ssh server on port 443, not because of the slightly earlier checks for identify files.  TCP port 443 is typically used for https servers; ssh servers by default run on TCP port 22.

Comment: @user4556274 I used port 443 because 22 was blocked by firewall. There was SVN server on the other side but https connection didn't work for some reason so I wanted to try to connect through ssh with port 443. But I guess it can't work that way. Nevermind, thanks for help ;)

Comment: Any TCP-based protocol can run on any TCP port, but _most_ servers follow convention for assigned numbers.  You can use `telnet` or `nc` to see if an `sshd` server is running on a given port, e.g. `nc 192.168.1.1 22` or `nc 192.168.1.1 443`.  If the server responds `SSH-2.0-someidentifier`, you can `ssh` to the server on that port.  If the server **does not** respond with the ssh version+identifier string, you can't `ssh` no matter how you change your local configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the routine `ssh` client initialization.  It should do no harm to look for (and confirm the non-existence of) the default identity files when you are not using asymmetric key authentication.

The `ssh` client adds pathnames for all default identity file paths to its list of identity files in [`readconf.c`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/readconf.c?rev=1.279&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)`:fill_default_options()`

```
if (options->num_identity_files == 0) {
    add_identity_file(options, "~/", _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_RSA, 0);
    add_identity_file(options, "~/", _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_DSA, 0);
    add_identity_file(options, "~/", _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_ECDSA, 0);
    add_identity_file(options, "~/",
        _PATH_SSH_CLIENT_ID_ED25519, 0);
}
```

and then iterates over all identity files in the list (both defaults from above and any added by user configuration) in [`ssh.c`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh.c?rev=1.464&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)`:load_public_identity_files()`, which is where the `debug1` messages you are seeing are generated.

<sup>The source code linked and quoted is from a newer version of OpenSSH than you are using—with different default identity files—but the code flow would be similar.</sup>

Comment: Yes but if I turned off pubkey authetification, why is it still looking for identity files? It doesn't even ask for password as I require it in config file and closes connection unexpectedly.

Comment: @MPython Not sure if that's your problem, but it isn't enough to specify `PreferredAuthentications password`, you have to also specify `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

Comment: @MPython, as I wrote, loading the default key files is part of the default client initialization.  Disabling pubkey authentication will not allow _use_ of the keys, but there is no option to disable _checking for their presence_.  If you really object to these checks, you would need to compile your own `ssh` client with the relevant code removed or disabled.